# How do you geometrically interpret a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm trying to geometrically understand the following linear transofrmations, given that the vector **w** is fixed and of length 1.

a) $u \mapsto (u\cdot w)w$

b) $u \mapsto u - (u\cdot w)w$

c) $u \mapsto w\times (u - (u\cdot w)w)$

How can I possibly interpret these geometrically? I'd be glad if you could share some nice tips in order to geometrically interpret any linear transformation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of $\times$ suggests that you are working on $\Bbb R^3$. I will assume that.

a) This is just the orthogonal projection on the line $\Bbb Rw$.

b) This is the orthogonal projection on the plane $w^\perp$.

c) Note that $w\times w=0\implies w\times\bigl(u-(u\cdot w)w\bigr)=w\times u$. So, this is just the vector product by $w$.

This works in these three cases. I am not suggesting that this gives a clue about how to find a geometric interpretation for *every* linear transformation.

Comment: I'm pretty good at geomtrically interpret linear transformations if they're on matrix form. But, I still can't really understand these transformations when they're on this vector type of form. I think I'll have to study the geometrical interpretation of the dot and cross product, in order to understand this better? Or what do you think? How can I better understand this? Btw, thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, you should study the geometrical meaning of the dot product and of the cross product. By the way, it is often explained that $u\cdot v$ is defined so that, if $\|v\|=1$, then $(u\cdot v)v$ is the orthogonal projection of $u$ on the line $\Bbb Rv$.